# Using Join and Insert Statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have an insert statement like this

```
INSERT INTO T_WorkContents ( user_id, working_date, working_start_time,  
                             working_end_time, break_time, holiday_mark,
                             overtime_hours, overtime_reason, work_detail,
                             remarks, regist_user, regist_date,
                             update_user, update_date )  

VALUES ( '00005', '2015-02-05', '8:0',
         '17:0', '0:0', '0',
         '0:0', NULL, NULL,
          NULL, '00005', current_timestamp(),
         '00005', current_timestamp()
);
```

I want to check whether the user is already deleted when insert the new row by join the table workcontent with the table user info on `user_id` and the condition is `where userinfo.delete_flag = 0`.

is there any way to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If the user is deleted then you don't want to perform the insert query?

Comment: Do you mean you want to block the insert if the user already exist ?

Comment: @Cyclone, yes, pretty much similar to what you think except that the user still able to to insert query but there is 0 row effected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question. But if you would like to only perform the insertion if the corresponding user exists and is marked as not deleted in your other table this should work:

```
INSERT INTO T_WorkContents ( user_id, working_date, working_start_time,  
                             working_end_time, break_time, holiday_mark,
                             overtime_hours, overtime_reason, work_detail,
                             remarks, regist_user, regist_date,
                             update_user, update_date )  

SELECT '00005', '2015-02-05', '8:0',
       '17:0', '0:0', '0',
       '0:0', NULL, NULL,
        NULL, '00005', current_timestamp(),
       '00005', current_timestamp()
FROM userinfo ui 
WHERE ui.user_id = '00005' && ui.delete_flag = 0
```

If the `userinfo` doesn't contain a row with a `user_id` equal to `00005` and a `delete_flag` that is set to 0 then the select will return no rows and the insert query will in turn affect no rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WHERE EXISTS.  Try below

```
INSERT INTO funds (field1, field2)
values (x, xx)
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT * 
   FROM table
   WHERE userid = your_user_id
);
```